# How to do dynamic elements in a v-if statement correctly?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, expression

I'm super new, and stumbling through learning vue. and hoping someone can help with a statement i'm trying to write.

```
<template>
<div id="transfer-time">
      <div class="content has-left-text">
          <div v-if="transfer === true"  v-bind:class="{'darkQues': darkMode}" >
                <p>you need to email {{ this.name }} for further assistance.</p>
                    <center><b>email {{ this.email }}</b></center>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  var transfer = {
      transferName: function(xfer) {
        return this.name + "" , this.email + "";
        }
      }
  var xfer = [{
    name: "john doe",
    email: "1@example.com"
  }, 
  {
    name: "john dope",
    email: "2@example.com"
  },
  {
    name: "jane doe",
    email: "3@example.com"
  },
  {
    name: "jane dope",
    email: "4@example.com"
  }]
</script>
```

At the end of the day im really just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Is all this code in a `.vue` file? You don't seem to be exporting anything. What is `transfer === true` supposed to do, because the only other thing called `transfer` appears to be an object? The 'variables' in a template are properties of the associated `Vue` instance, so to access something called `transfer` in your template you'll need to create a property called `transfer`. Typically that would be via `data` or `computed`. Beyond that, could you provide a clear description of what you want the code to do, because it's difficult to guess what your intentions are from the existing code?

Comment: essentially its if you click buttonA is will give value 1, if you click buttonB it will give value 2 but all displaying the same message save for the (name, email) variable. I'm sure I am butchering the code. I have not implemented the buttons on it as i am just trying to understand the logic.

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html)

Comment: I'm not going to disagree, but I learn better by going in and breaking it and doing than reading. That's just the best way I learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but based on your comment I think this is somewhere close:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      selected: null,
    
      xfer: [
        {
          name: "john doe",
          email: "1@example.com"
        }, 
        {
          name: "john dope",
          email: "2@example.com"
        },
        {
          name: "jane doe",
          email: "3@example.com"
        },
        {
          name: "jane dope",
          email: "4@example.com"
        }
      ]    
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onClick (item) {
      this.selected = item
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button
      v-for="item in xfer"
      :key="item.email"
      @click="onClick(item)"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </button>
  </div>
  <p v-if="selected">
    You need to email {{ selected.name }} for further assistance.
    <strong>{{ selected.email }}</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

If you wanted to write the same thing as a `.vue` file you would get rid of the `new Vue` and `el` parts and just use `export default` instead.

The key thing to appreciate is that when you access identifiers such as `xfer` and `selected` in the template they are just properties of the `Vue` instance. In the template you should drop the `this.` prefix but it's still required within the JavaScript portion (e.g. see inside `onClick`).

In a typical application you will only create one `Vue` instance directly using `new Vue` but every child component will have its own `Vue` instance created behind the scenes. Properties created via `props`, `data`, `computed`, etc. will all be exposed via that associated instance.

When a button is clicked I've chosen to store the relevant entry from `xfer` in `selected`. That isn't the only way this could be done. e.g. You could store an id or an index. In that scenario you might then have a `computed` property that finds the corresponding object to expose it to the template.